# Vectorizing ARD (Automatic Relevance Determination) kernel implementation in Gaussian processes

Tags: numpy, pytorch, vectorization, matrix-multiplication, gaussian-process

I am trying to implement an ARD kernel with NumPy as given in the GPML book (M3 from Equation 5.2).
[image]

I am struggling in vectorizing this equation for NxM kernel computation. I have tried the following non-vectorized version. Can someone help in vectorizing this in NumPy/PyTorch?

```
import numpy as np
N = 30 # Number of data points in X1
M = 40 # Number of data points in X2
D = 6  # Number of features (ARD dimensions)

X1 = np.random.rand(N, D)
X2 = np.random.rand(M, D)
Lambda = np.random.rand(D, 1)
L_inv = np.diag(np.random.rand(D))
sigma_f = np.random.rand()

K = np.empty((N, M))
for n in range(N):
  for m in range(M):
    M3 = Lambda@Lambda.T + L_inv**2
    d = (X1[n,:] - X2[m,:]).reshape(-1,1)
    K[n, m] = sigma_f**2 * np.exp(-0.5 * d.T@M3@d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the rules of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) and the neat NumPy function [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy-einsum) to vectorize array operations. In few words, broadcasting allows us to operate with arrays in one-liners by adding new dimensions to the resulting array, while `einsum` allows us to perform operations with multiple arrays by explicitly working in the index notation (instead of matrices).

Luckily, no loops are necessary to calculate your kernel. Please see below the vectorized solution, `ARD_kernel` function, which is about 30x faster in my machine than the original loopy version. Now, `einsum` is usually as fast as it gets, but it's possible that there are faster methods though, I've not checked anything else (e.g. usual `@` operator instead of `einsum`).

Also, there is a missing term in the code (the Kronecker delta), I don't know if it was omitted in purpose (let me know if you have problems implementing it and I'll edit the answer).

```
import numpy as np
N = 300 # Number of data points in X1
M = 400 # Number of data points in X2
D = 6  # Number of features (ARD dimensions)

np.random.seed(1)  # Fix random seed for reproducibility
X1 = np.random.rand(N, D)
X2 = np.random.rand(M, D)
Lambda = np.random.rand(D, 1)
L_inv = np.diag(np.random.rand(D))
sigma_f = np.random.rand()

# Loopy function
def ARD_kernel_loops(X1, X2, Lambda, L_inv, sigma_f):
    K = np.empty((N, M))
    M3 = Lambda@Lambda.T + L_inv**2
    for n in range(N):
        for m in range(M):
            d = (X1[n,:] - X2[m,:]).reshape(-1,1)
            K[n, m] = np.exp(-0.5 * d.T@M3@d)
    return K * sigma_f**2
    
# Vectorized function
def ARD_kernel(X1, X2, Lambda, L_inv, sigma_f):
    M3 = Lambda.squeeze()*Lambda + L_inv**2  # Use broadcasting to avoid transpose
    d = X1[:,None] - X2[None,...]            #  Use broadcasting to avoid loops
    
    # order=F for memory layout (as your arrays are (N,M,D) instead of (D,N,M))
    return sigma_f**2 * np.exp(-0.5 * np.einsum("ijk,kl,ijl->ij", d, M3, d, order = 'F'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! just as an addition, if ```Lambda``` is ```(D, k)``` instead of ```(D, 1)``` (as per the book), your answer still works if we use ```M3 = Lambda@Lambda.T + L_inv**2``` in vectorized version. Beautiful einsum!!

Answer (score 0):

There is perhaps an additional optimisation. The examples of the M matrices given are all positive definite. This means that the Cholesky decomposition can be applied, wo that we can find upper triangular U so that

```
M = U'*U
```

The point of this is that if we apply U to the xs, so

```
y[p] = U*x[p] p=1..
```

Then

```
(x[p]-x[q])'*M*(x[p]-x[q]) = (y[p]-y[q])'*(y[p]-y[q])
```

Thus if there are N vectors x each of dimension d,
we convert the N squared O(d squared) operations on the LHS to N squared O(d) operations on the RHS

This has cost an extra choleski decompositon (O(d cubed))
and N O( d squared) applications of U to the xs.